# Mapping Redux Store Data to FrontEnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-fullstack

I'm looking to map a store I have to the frontend. Please see below:

When a user searches, it makes a request and dispatches and action. E.g if I look up 'Data', I get data for all jobs with Data in the title.

https://gyazo.com/e8c086fa6c929c70863abb4551127d21

As you can see in the store, I have an action and I have in my store the following: job search, which fetches roles. I'd like to map these roles out by title to the front end section.

Please see my code below:

```
export function SearchBarTrialRedux(props) {

    const [isExpanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
    const [parentRef, isClickedOutside ] = useClickOutside();
    const inputRef = useRef();
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [jobPostings, setjobPostings] = useState([]);
    const [noRoles, setNoRoles] = useState(false)


    const expandedContainer = () => {
        setExpanded(true);
    }

    const collapseContainer = () => {
        setExpanded(false);
        setSearchQuery("");
         setLoading(false);
         setNoRoles(false);
        if (inputRef.current) inputRef.current.value = "";

      };


    useEffect(()=> {
        if(isClickedOutside)
            collapseContainer();
    }, [isClickedOutside])

    const [term, setTerm] = useState("")


    const dispatch = useDispatch();


    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLoading(true)
        fetchAsyncRoles(dispatch, term);
        setLoading(false)
    }
    
    return (
    <SearchBarContainer animate = {isExpanded ? "expanded" : "collapsed"} 
                        variants={containerVariants} transition={containerTransition} ref={parentRef}>
        <SearchInputContainer>
            <SearchIconSpan>
                <SearchIcon/>
            </SearchIconSpan>
            <GeneralContainerForm onSubmit={changeHandler}>
            <SearchInput placeholder = "Search for Roles" 
                                onFocus={expandedContainer} 
                                ref={inputRef}
                                value={term}
                                onChange={(e)=> setTerm(e.target.value)}
                                />
            </GeneralContainerForm>
            <AnimatePresence>
                {isExpanded && (<CloseIconSpan  key="close-icon" 
                                inital={{opacity:0, rotate: 0}} 
                                animate={{opacity:1, rotate: 180}} 
                                exit={{opacity:0, rotate: 0}} 
                                transition={{duration: 0.2}}
                                onClick={collapseContainer}
                                onChange={(e)=> setTerm(e.target.value)}
                                >
                    <CloseIcon/>
                </CloseIconSpan>
                 )}
            </AnimatePresence>
        </SearchInputContainer>
        {isExpanded && <LineSeperator/>}
        {isExpanded && <SearchContent>
        
        {!isLoading && !noRoles && (
        <Typography color="gray" display="flex" flex="0.2" alignSelf="center" justifySelf="center">
                Start typing to search
        </Typography>
        )}
        
        {!isLoading && <>
            {jobPostings.map((roles) => (
                <JobSection
                    title={roles.title}
                />
            ))}    
        </>}
        </SearchContent>}
    </SearchBarContainer>
    )
}
```

What is the correct manner to do this? Is it mapstatetoprops? If so what's the proper way.

I am looking to implement further actions and the majority of the project is on the basis of this redux store concept, but I am quite new!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not use `mapStateToProps` nowadays except in legacy class components.

Instead, you use `useSelector`. So if you want to select something from `state.foo.bar`, you do

```js
const bar = useSelector(state => state.foo.bar)
```

If you are just learning Redux I would *highly* recommend that you follow the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) as a lot of other sources out there are quite outdated. Modern Redux does not use `switch..case` reducers, `ACTION_TYPE`s, immutable reducer logic, hand-written action creators, `createStore` or `connect`/`mapStateToProps` any more and is about 1/4 of the code of that old style of Redux using all these concepts.

Comment: Hi @phry thanks for the info. So for this situation I'd use selector and then select the store key, e.g in this store I'd select from jobsearch.title and then map this in the html? Is that roughly what it would look like. Thanks for sending so much information by the way. I greatly greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Generally, yes.  Probably from `state.jobsearch.title`, but that is depending on how you set up your store.
But please really go through that tutorial.

Comment: Thankyou Phry, i will look through it diligently. I appreciate your work on the redux project and everything you have contributed to it. Your above comment has also made me think potentially i have setup my redux store etc in quite a legacy manner. I do appreciate this. Would love to add/join a discord server with you if possible as I'm always learning and keen to pickup all skills

Comment: Most maintainers and a lot of very knowledgeable users are in the redux channel over at reactiflux. But please keep questions to the channel and we answer when we can - private messages would mean we have no chance to do anything else.